# spinner setSelection: unable to set position after orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, spinner, android-spinner

After orientation change I can restore spinner position by using:

```
mySpinner.setSelection(restorePosition, true);
```

If I don't use second parameter, the spinner defaults to index 0;
This workaround works for OS 2.x and up, but still has no effect on  4.0 (spinner reverts to position zero).

Can someone please suggest a solution?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the issue was in how listeners are stacked/executed in 4.x. I was resetting restorePosition variable to 0 right after mySpinner.setSelection call. Moving restorePosition variable reset to the "mySpinner" listener solved that problem. I suppose another way to do this would have been to implement a wait().  Maybe this will be useful for someone else.